# Using Jquery Mobile to display charts(d3js) on mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile to create a HTML5 Mobile Application which would be able to display charts which are created using [d3js](http://d3js.org/). These charts would be created on client side, however the data would be retrieved via server. The JQM pages are static HTML pages which would request data from server and create impromptu charts. However, I am having difficulty in understanding JQM ajax/hash mapping. When I redirect a request to another page it is unable to run javascript on that page. Hence I have used `window.location.href = a.html`  to change pages instead of $.mobile.changePage(a.html).

Each data page has an id so that it can be cached, how can I then create a new page link and feed it data.

I have 2 files : `index.html` which contains list of data which a user can choose to see and then another file which is `chart.html` which contains information on how to create a chart using Javascript Ajax to fetch data from server. How is this possible using JQM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have already run through [JQM Page Links](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) and [JQM Page Scripting](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Since JQM fetches all subsequent pages via (Hi)Ajax and inserts their `<body>` tag into the current DOM; the `<script>`s defined on your subsequent pages are not executed.

You will need to include all your scripts in the `<head>` of your first page - index.html

For passing parameters between pages; you could simply use the plugins mentioned at the bottom of the [JQM Page Scripting](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) page

Although I personally just use the $.data() function :D

Comment: I was wondering how to give each chart module(each data-role="page") a unique id as I would only know the charttype and chartpage at runtime. If I don't give a unique id then it would only render the same page. Wouldn't it?

Comment: You don't really need to build a separate page for each chart type. Rather just render the correct chart-type in the content of a single "chartPage" based on user-selected type on "inputPage"